# Making HTTP request from an apache2 module (c++)

Tags: c++, apache, http, httprequest, apache2-module

My apache2 module written in c++ works just fine, it handles "page.xyz"-like requests from browser clients, and it can return the appropriate result.

What I need now is to use my module as a client to another server: make a HTTP (GET) request and get the response (GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?...).

Does apache has a magic can do this, or do I have to deal with sockets and make HTTP packets manually? What is the best way to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are on your own with the HTTP client. Probably the easiest way to make an HTTP connection is to use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/). On linux it should be installable from your distro's repositories.

Comment: Curl works well. I'm working on windows, but trying to write portable code. I was surprised when it linked even "CreateCompatibleDC" (!? :-) ), then I had some troubles with certificates, but finally curl seems to be a good solution and handles redirects and https well. Sry I can't you rank up, have no reputation.